# TypeScript: constraint in constructor

Tags: typescript

ExclusiveValues is data structure like radio button.

```
type FilteredProperty<T,U> = {[K in keyof T]: T[K] extends U ? K : never}[keyof T];

class ExclusiveValues<T,U> {
  private currentActiveObject: T|null = null;

  constructor(
    private propertyName: FilteredProperty<T,U>,
    private targetArray: T[],
    private activeValue: T[FilteredProperty<T,U>],
    private defaultValue: T[FilteredProperty<T,U>]) {}

  setActive(target: T) {
    if(this.currentActiveObject != null) {
      this.currentActiveObject[this.propertyName] = this.defaultValue;
    }
    target[this.propertyName] = this.activeValue;
    this.currentActiveObject = target;
  }
}
```

**first case** ok

```
//ok
const test = new ExclusiveValues<target,boolean>("PropertyA",sampleArray,true,false);
```

**second case** error !!

```
class ExclusiveBooleanValues<T> extends ExclusiveValues<T,boolean> {
  constructor(propertyName: FilteredProperty<T,boolean>,targetArray: T[]) {
    //Error!! Argument of type 'true' is not assignable to parameter of type 'T[{ [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends boolean ? K : never; }[keyof T]]'.
    super(propertyName,targetArray,true,false); 
  }
}
```

I don't know why it doesn't work...
Why?

[this is playground code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#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-gBt6-o6oGwQYwiytYAD0WE4Fw9gdF0wYhFqeoQAA7lA7heD4-iBMEoQhsApCNs2rbsJQAxXlBGS3suCyrhA64oLcpDdMEpBgTimEOM4bgeEEtEQN2U7sT6oTENQsjyEoVEKd4Xz0SEYSsdOHEMMMC79r0wD9AMEbbM6vxooCUEmapbaUGJFbXCJdwSLiFlBjhripP02ralA67nJ4SzpFAAjBuA0AAOTiRAKVsMo7A4FqclwOc7COAULbBjgMRnNGAIJYIpapcQjD0FALBsJwJiJSI9zMFI2k8rppnseomhQNoeioOYAbGLwHXCMIKXspCiiePg9nAU53lUr5onpZJsHSVAwxFoSLQ2EAA)

Comment: It's pretty complicated and good question. I think, on the first case, `T` (aka `sampleArray`) is explicitly defined and Typescript can infer the remaining types. However, on the second case, `T` is not known and it may not even have `boolean` properties. That's why it gives error.